# Mongoose return id instead of _id in populate method

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-populate

I have two related models: `Recipe` and `User`.

When I fetch a recipe and the related user from the database using `populate()`, I want the returned user object to have the `id` property instead of the `_id` property.

```
const recipe = await Recipe.findOne({ _id }).populate('user', '-password');
```

When I log the value of the user model, I want to get this:

```
{
  id: 5eea82b11a97e9429ca61778,
  name: 'John Doe',
  email: 'johndoe@gmail.com'
}
```

I tried adding the `id` property to the user object, it didn't change anything. I still got the `_id` property.

```
recipe.user = { ...recipe.user, id: recipe.user_id };
```

Comment: Is there any particular reason you want `id` instead of `_id`?

Comment: @Shadab In other parts of my app, I was able to user `id` instead of `_id`, but it doesn't work in this populate method. I want to use `id` instead of `_id` for consistency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    noteSchema.set('toJSON', {
  transform: (document, returnedObject) => {
    returnedObject.id = returnedObject._id.toString()
    delete returnedObject._id
    delete returnedObject.__v
  }
})
```

This is what i use to remove the underscores - You can just transform the document and delete the bits you dont want